# How to reliably find the global minimum of a rational function?

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion, roots, rational-functions

I am stuck at a algorithm problem. I was assigned the following problem:
Given a finite Taylor expansion in some degree $n$: $$\text{TE} = \sum_{j=0}^{n}{c_j}{x^j}$$ with all real coefficients $c_j$ known except for a single coefficient $c_k$, I need to find the minimum value for $c_k$ such that $\text{TE} = 0$ for some value of $x$. So I have tried to isolate it, which gives a rational function in $x$:
$$c_k = \frac{\sum_{j \neq k}c_jx^j}{x^k}$$
However now I am stuck. Normally to find the global minimum of a rational function  you differentiate the function then set the derivative to $0$ and find all critical points. But when the degree is high, I don't know about a stable method to find all the roots of this rational function derivative. We were only taught the Newton's method so far, but it is unstable. So is there a stable numerical method that can find all the roots of the function in a low time complexity? We are not allowed to exceed quadratic time complexity.

Possibly I was told that there exists an algorithm called VCA (Vincent Collins Akritas) for polynomials, but it requires the Budan's theorem to determine the number of roots within an interval. Is there an extension for rational functions? This would allow an $O(n \log n)$ algorithm.

Comment: The coefficients are all real? Root creation under real coefficients happens in pairs, changing a pair of complex conjugate roots into a pair of real roots. At the transition point, you get a double root. That would suggest to compute the discriminant with $c_k$ as parameter and apply root finding, but both stages are above $O(n\log n)$.

Comment: Yes in our case the coefficients are real. We are looking therefore for real roots. Sorry,  I will make it clear.

Comment: Your rational function is just a finite [Laurent series](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series)

Comment: @D.W. : For $c_k=0$ there is no root. Your procedure provides a $c_k$ with real roots. The taks is to find the smallest, closest to $0$, value of $c_k$ with real roots. This can be achieved by taking the derivative of this last equation and finding a root of it. To reliably solve this, one needs to find all the roots, or at least all the real ones. But that brings us back to at least quadratic complexity.

Comment: Thank you for explaining to me so patiently.  I apologize for taking up your time with such an ill-informed comment.

Comment: @ТymaGaidash Thanks for the insight, I searched a bit and found it would also be a Padé approximant, but are there useful properties for these that will help in the task? I can't seem to find any.

Comment: I found this paper on the global minimization of rational functions, it should be helpful. I will try to read through it as it seems quite advanced. https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~demmel/Demmel_pubs_07_11_final/J74_Global_Minimization_Rational_Functions_Nearest_GCDs.pdf